# carrierwave issue updating user profil or banner picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

So far,i got a Model "utilisateur" with basic informations. I want to add a banner picture.
I ran `rails g uploader banner` , `rails g migration AddBannerToUtilisateur banner:string`, and add `mount_uploader :banner BannerUploader` to the model ( of course i ran db:migrate and restart the server ).

If i create a new "utilisateur", i think upload should work (it works for the "utilisateur"'s posts ), but here, i just want to update the current "utilisateur" and attach a new banner.

I can't use `UPDATE` from the controller because i will have to provide all the "utilisateur" infos. I want to make a separate `updatebanner` function.

Here is my form :

```
<%=form_for :utilisateur, :url => updatecover_path, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|%>  
<%=f.file_field :banner%>  
<%=f.submit%>
<%end%>
```

Here is my controller :

> def updatecover
>   @utilisateur = Utilisateur.find(current_user.id)
>   @utilisateur.banner = params[:utilisateur[:banner]]
>   @utilisateur.save!
>
> end

I know and i understand why this function is not working, but i don't know what to do. Can't find a precise answer or tips on the web.

Here is the request :

> Started POST "/updatecover" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-04 12:26:53 +0200
>   Processing by UtilisateursController#updatecover as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"rncjd3meVuQuSLHxPrwbtEF7Ye0hH7pcNxcLoYy2oeQ=",
>   "utilisateur"=>{"banner"=>#,
>   @original_fil ename="2048.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"utilisateur[banner]\"; filename= \"2048.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type:
>   image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Save Utilisateur"}

here's my route:

> match "updatecover" => "utilisateurs#updatecover", :as =>
>   :updatecover,:via => [:get,:post]

I think my error is basic. But i can't find out.

Thanks

Here's the full log

> Started POST "/updatecover" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-04 15:42:19 +0200
>   Processing by UtilisateursController#updatecover as HTML Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"rncjd3meVuQuSLHxPrwbtEF7Ye0hH7pcNxcLoYy2oeQ=",
>   "utilisateur"=>{"banner"=>#, @original_fil
>   ename="shift-s3ctor-airstrip-attack-october-2013-preview-36304
>   (1).jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposit ion:
>   form-data; name=\"utilisateur[banner]\";
>   filename=\"shift-s3ctor-airstrip-attack-october-2013-preview-36304
>   (1).jpg\"\r\nC ontent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Save
>   Utilisateur"} Utilisateur Load (0.3ms) SELECT "utilisateurs".* FROM
>   "utilisateurs" WHERE "utilisateurs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 [["id", 7]]
>   CACHE (0.0ms) SELECT "utilisateurs".* FROM "utilisateurs" WHERE
>   "utilisateurs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 [["id", 7]] CACHE (0.0ms) SELECT
>   "utilisateurs".* FROM "utilisateurs" WHERE "utilisateurs"."id" = $1
>   LIMIT 1 [["id", 7]] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms
>
> TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
>   app/controllers/utilisateurs_controller.rb:28:in []'
>
> app/controllers/utilisateurs_controller.rb:28:inupdatecover'

Comment: What do you mean by printing ?

Comment: What's the output for user.banner.url

Comment: The current output is nil , because the form submit doesn't trigger the upload itslef. In fact, it does nothing.

Comment: its the same. Im french, utilisateur is user, i edit my post.

Comment: What do you mean by `I know and i understand why this function is not working, but i don't know what to do.`? Why you think your code is not working? Also, could you share the complete server log generated when you `updatecover`.

Comment: It is not working because it does not trigger any action when i submit, and @utilisateur.banner = params[:utilisateur[:banner]] mean nothing, i know its not the right way to update the picture, but i didnt find the right way over the internet. Here's the full log:

Comment: @AWalex Post the log in the question, not as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `updatecover` action as below:

```
def updatecover
  @utilisateur = Utilisateur.find(current_user.id)
  @utilisateur.banner = params[:utilisateur][:banner] ## Notice how params is called
  @utilisateur.save!
end
```

If you notice the `params` hash:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rncjd3meVuQuSLHxPrwbtEF7Ye0hH7pcNxcLoYy2oeQ=", "utilisateur"=>{"banner"=>#, @original_fil ename="2048.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"utilisateur[banner]\"; filename= \"2048.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Save Utilisateur"}
```

`params[:utilisateur]` would give you:

```
{"banner"=>#, @original_fil ename="2048.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"utilisateur[banner]\"; filename= \"2048.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}
```

Now, to get `banner` out of that, what you need is `params[:utilisateur][:banner]` which would yield:

```
#, @original_fil ename="2048.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"utilisateur[banner]\"; filename= \"2048.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">
```

Comment: Wow, i wasn't that far ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @AWalex Glad to help. :) Make sure that you delete the server log from the answer and add it to the question instead.